# Autoform object field

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a collection of articles and a collection of categories for this articles. The article have only one category. I need when adding an article when write a category if it exist add a id of category, if not - create a category and then add an id.
How can i make it with autoform?

Comment: Could you please tell us what you tried already?